# $P(A) = a, P(B) = b > 0$, how to show that $P(A \cap B) \ge a+b-1$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Not sure how to prove this. Problem doesn't give information about if event $A$ and event $B$ are independent or not. I understand that $P(A \cap B)$ would be upper bounded by $1$. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try breaking it up into cases?

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean P(A or B)?

Answer (score 3):

Use the inclusion-exclusion principle and the fact that probability is bounded between $0$ and $1$, i.e., 
$$P(A \cup B)= P(A)+P(B) - P(A\cap B) \le 1,$$
hence, 
$$
P(A\cap B) \ge a + b - 1.
$$

Answer (score 2):

$P(A \cap B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cup B)= a+b - P(A \cup B) \ge a+b - 1 $, and this is because $P(A\cup B) \le 1$